# Ordering by the row with more match value inside IN clause

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables here

```
         posts                               tags
[   id         title    ]          [   pid          tag   ]
[   1            X      ]          [    1            php  ]
[   2            Y      ]          [    1            pdo  ]
[   3            Z      ]          [    2            php  ]
                                   [    2            ajax ]
                                   [    3            pdo  ]
```

and i apply this query on both of these tables

```
$query = "
SELECT a.title FROM posts a
INNER JOIN tags b ON a.id = b.pid
WHERE b.tag IN ($tags)
";
```

right now if

```
$tags = [php, pdo];
```

i expect to get the row with the more matched values of the `$tags` So the order would be `X->Y->Z`

And if

`$tags = [php, pdo, ajax]`

i expect to get `X->Y->Z` too, But in both queries the order isn't like that at all, It is more like ordered by the name or the tags alphabets, How can i get it ordered by the highest matched rows, And if possible, The only row with all matches values only.

Comment: `i expect to get the row with the more matched values of the ` can you explain? what does "more matched values" mean? A match is a match, it can't "match more"...?

Comment: @dognose like if i `$tags = [php, pdo]`, since the `title=x` has 2 matches`php, pdo`, I expected it to be the first of all the returned rows, then `title=y` has only `pdo` matched, Same as `title=z` since both has the same amount of matches rows, I expect them to be random or ordered by something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's only about the occurences of a tag, you can group and sort by count.

Something like (untested)

```
$query = "
SELECT a.title, GROUP_CONCAT(b.tag) as tags, count(b.tag) AS relevance FROM posts a
INNER JOIN tags b ON a.id = b.pid
WHERE b.tag IN ($tags)
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY count(b.tag) DESC
";
```

(order `DESC` or `ASC`, depending on what you would have topmost)

But still, this would only consider "real" matches, any typo like "pgp" rather than "php" would kill the quality of the search result.